# Primefaces theme not applying in Liferay portlet

Tags: java, primefaces, liferay-theme

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.0 in my portlet project. I'm facing a problem in applying a theme. I added the all-themes.jar to use the flick theme in the project and configured in web.xml as following.

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>flick</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

But not theme is applied in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look at [this post](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/18944300) in the Liferay Faces forums.